# Creating a thesis cover page with two images

Tags: covers

my code is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

    \newcommand{\titulo}    {titulo}
    \newcommand{\alumnos}   {author  %\\ Nombre completo segundo alumno
                                    }
    \newcommand{\profguia}  {TUTOR: name}


        %   \newcommand{\coguia}    {Profesor Co-guía: Nombre completo profesor} 
         \newcommand{\coguia}   {  }        

    \newcommand{\mes}   {OCTUBRE}  % Mes de entrega  (primera letra en mayúzcula)
    \newcommand{\yeaR}  {2018} % Año de entrega 
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\LARGE{university of arkansas law school }\\

}
\vspace{65mm}

%Título del trabajo
\Large{\textbf{\titulo.}} 

\vspace{55mm}
\Large{\textbf{\alumnos}}
%\Large{\textbf{Nombre completo alumno}} % en caso de ser dos alumnos incorporar '\\ para separarlos (Alumno 1 \\alumno 2)

\vspace{30mm}

\end{center}
\vspace{10mm}

\begin{center}

\end{center}
%\vspace{5mm}
\vfill

\begin{center}
\Large{\mes, \yeaR}
\end{center}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

I want to put images on the sides, how do I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <===============================================

    \newcommand{\titulo}    {titulo}
    \newcommand{\alumnos}   {author  %\\ Nombre completo segundo alumno
                                    }
    \newcommand{\profguia}  {TUTOR: name}


        %   \newcommand{\coguia}    {Profesor Co-guía: Nombre completo profesor} 
         \newcommand{\coguia}   {  }        

    \newcommand{\mes}   {OCTUBRE}  % Mes de entrega  (primera letra en mayúzcula)
    \newcommand{\yeaR}  {2018} % Año de entrega 


\begin{document}


{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\begin{minipage}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a} % <========================
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{5cm}
\begin{center}
\LARGE{UNIVERSIDAD }\\\Large{FACULTAD \\CARRERA}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{3cm}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b} % <========================
\end{minipage}
}
\vspace{65mm}

\begin{center}
%Título del trabajo
\Large{\textbf{\titulo.}} 

\vspace{55mm}
\Large{\textbf{\alumnos}}
%\Large{\textbf{Nombre completo alumno}} % en caso de ser dos alumnos incorporar '\\ para separarlos (Alumno 1 \\alumno 2)

\vspace{30mm}

\end{center}
\vspace{10mm}

\begin{center}

\end{center}
%\vspace{5mm}
\vfill

\begin{center}
\Large{\mes, \yeaR}
\end{center}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\end{document}
```

results in

[image]